# Beamer: flip from slide to slide regardless of \pause when desired

Tags: beamer, pause

Suppose I have a presentation with many `\pause` commands. Sometimes, I get questions that can be answered by going back a few slides. Is there a way to go back (and later forward) while ignoring the `\pause` commands? Say jump from full slide to full slide.

I'm aware that it is possible to get rid of `\pause` by writing `\documentclass[handout]{beamer}`. But I like the `\pause` s while I present and would like to skip them when needed without recompiling the whole presentation (which would be impossible during a presentation).

Ideally, I would like to use a clicker for my presentation and have a button that can go as usual from `\pause` to `\pause` and one that can go faster from slide to slide.

I noticed that beamersybmols appear when using `\pause` . I usually deleted but they could be part of the solution. I'm also open to hacks, say compiling the document once with and once without [handout] so that I'd have 2 pdf files. For this, there would have to be a way to let the [handout] pdf 'follow' the `\pause` pdf file. Then I could use my pdf reader to switch between the pdfs. Perhaps the 2 documents could even be glued together into one.

Here

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1} a\pause b\pause c \end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 2} d\pause e\pause f \end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 3} g\pause h\pause i % now suppose I get a question that requires me to go back to frame 1. I don't want to click through the 2 pause commands of frame 2. \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The navigation symbols at the bottom of the slide will take you back/forth by whole frames:

[image]

Comment: I might be missing something but this does not work for me. When I compile my MWE and see slide 1 with 'a' and click on that button, I get to 'b'. When I press it again, I get to 'c'. When I press it again, nothing happens. (I'm using adobe reader if that matters.)

Comment: This is weird. I recompiled my MWE again (twice) and cannot replicate what I reported before nor what you found. Now, when I start with 'a' on slide one and click on the button, I get to 'd' on slide 2. When I click the button again, I get to 'g' on slide 3. When I click it again, I get to 'ghi' on slide 3. When I click the backwards button, I get to 'g'. When I click on the backwards button again, nothing happens. Either I'm lost or mysterious forces are at work here.

Comment: @user278486 Is your beamer version up-to-date and which engine do you use to compile? From ghi backwards should bring you to the slide with def, not g

Comment: I just updated my beamer package. I'm using pdflatex to compile. (I hope that is what you mean by 'compilation engine'.) I do it twice for good measure. On my pdf reader, the MWE still behaves as in my second comment.

Comment: Could it have something to do with my MWE being wrong? I was thinking that perhaps there should be a `\pause` after c,f and h but that doesn't change the behavior. Perhaps the button you mentioned means 'go forward' across 2 or 3 `\pause` symbols (or to the next slide)?

Comment: yes, pdflatex is fine (I was wondering about a problem with the link area I recently fixed, but that was just for xelatex). Other than the missing line break before `\end{frame}`, your mwe seems fine. The arrows jump to the last slide of the previous frame and the first slide of the next frame, respectively, no matter how many overlays there are. Are you sure that you click on the arrows and not icon itself? This would explain the jumping to the start of the current frame instead of the end of the previous frame.

Comment: If you get too close to the symbol, you'll hit this button instead of the arrow https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNMt6.png

Comment: With your updated figure, it makes sense now! So I start at 'a', click on the arrow to the left and get to 'd'. That makes sense since 'd' is the first slide on the second frame. It also explains the issues I had with replicating the behavior I observed. There are 4 buttons where I only saw 3 symbols.

Comment: yes, it is a bit crowed :)

Comment: Just to understand: To go backward, one can click on the leftmost of the 4 buttons you mentioned. To go forward, I would have to alternate between 'first slide next frame' and 'last slide current frame' to go through from full frame to full frame?

Comment: Ideally, I would prefer to have only two buttons, one for 'last slide previous frame' and one for 'last slide next frame'. But perhaps that is another question. What do you think?

Comment: Sure, you can ask a new question about this