# Customizing Beamersymbols

Tags: beamer, pause, frame

I find it tricky to click on the right beamersymbol and do not trust myself to do it during a presentation. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/654496/beamer-flip-from-slide-to-slide-regardless-of-pause-when-desired) for an illustration. So, I would like to reduce the number of beamer symbols, ideally to just two: 'last slide previous frame' to go backward and 'last slide next frame' to go forward. (Actually, the symbol 'last slide next frame' does not exist by default, so this might involve creating a new beamer symbol? Worst case, I could live with the symbol 'last slide previous frame' and 'last slide current frame' and go forward by switching between 'last slide current frame' and the usual 'next slide'.)

From page 72 of the [beamer documentation](https://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf), I know that I can narrow down the number of symbols to 4 by using

`\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\insertframenavigationsymbol}`.

[This might be too much for one question, but ideally, I would like to link the two beamersymbols described above to a clicker so that 1) the symbols do not clutter the slides and 2) I can use them without using a mouse. But having those two symbols would already be nice since I can go to the laptop and click on the symbols when asked a question that requires me to flick through slides fast. I'm also not sure whether it is possible to use a clicker like that.]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\insertframenavigationsymbol}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
a\pause
b\pause
c

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
d\pause
e\pause
f

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 3}
g\pause
h\pause
i% now suppose I get a question that requires me to go back to frame 1. I don't want to click through the 2 pause commands of frame 2.

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine the frame navigation symbol to just have the two links to the end of the previous frame and start of the next frame.

*(that's much easier to do than "last slide next frame", because beamer doesn't know yet how many slides the next frame might have. For the first slide of the next frame, all it needs to know how many slides the current frame has and add 1 to this)*

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 1}} % just for this example to see the links

\makeatletter
\def\insertframenavigationsymbol{%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{-1.5pt}{20pt}{5.5pt}
    \pgfuseobject{beamerframenavstrong}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{navigation symbols dimmed}
    \pgfuseobject{beamerframenavlight}%
  \end{pgfpicture}\kern-20pt%
  \hyperlinkframeendprev{\beamer@linkspace{10pt}}%
  \hyperlinkframestartnext{\beamer@linkspace{10pt}}}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\insertframenavigationsymbol}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
a\pause
b\pause
c
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
d\pause
e\pause
f
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 3}
g\pause
h\pause
i% now suppose I get a question that requires me to go back to frame 1. I don't want to click through the 2 pause commands of frame 2.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]