# Is it possible to use a keyboard shortcut to go back and forth between slides without pause?

Tags: beamer, overlays, pause, shortcut

My slides usually have a lot of overlays like

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\pause \item A
\pause \item B
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

The problem is that I go back and forth a lot during presentation and it makes the talk super slow.
There are two solutions which I' looking for:
Solution 1: Before telling what my problem is, I think my problem can be solved if we can assign specific keustrokes for going between slides without pause. Some thing like if I hit A then it will go back and if I hit B it goes to next slide.
Solution 2:redefining pause command:

The goal of pause for me is to let the  audience focus on one thing the first time I show it to them. If I go back and forth between slides, I don't want the pause to work. Hence I need two added behavior for \pause:
A) When hitting back button on keyboard we should be able to go straight to previous slide and previous item
B) After doing A , when going again the original slide which I presented once, it should transition without pause and go straight to the next slidd.

I know probably it can be done with use of toggle for each item but that is impractical for beamer files with many slids. Also I don't want to use buttons.

Comment: I know you said no to buttons, but the navigations symbols seems to be exactly he functionality you are asking for https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/654524/36296

Answer (score 1):

If you are on mac, you can for example use [Présentation.app](http://iihm.imag.fr/blanch/software/osx-presentation/) to view the pdf. This pdf viewer has keyboard shortcuts to jump between frames:

[image]

Comment: I present in different universities so it is very hard to install the app on their computer.

Comment: @Johns In this case you should abandon the idea of keyboard shortcuts. Whatever hack one might use to create such a shortcut will never work in each and every possible pdf viewer. I suggest to use the navigation symbols at the bottom of the slides instead.